# Xamarin: How to use the Dropbox v2 API

Tags: xamarin, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to a dropbox api v2 for my android application. But I couldn't find any references of how to start up with the library. From the api, I saw DropboxOAuth2Helper.GetAuthorize... class which I think I should be calling and it returned me the Uri. Where should I use the Uri it returned. Should I load on WebView.

Comment: Hey! Could you please post some code or a sample that I can use to diagnose the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Xamarin component? https://components.xamarin.com/view/dropboxcoreapiandroid
There is a "Getting Started" guide that should get you going if so.

Comment: Do _not_ use the Xamarin component, it is using v1 under the hood which is now completely shut down.